# Are alternate connection points on a PCB bad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, noise, connector, antenna

If a PCB is designed to provide two connection options for the same signal, for example it has a banana plug connector on one side of the PCB but also exposes the same signal on another side of the PCB through perhaps a large row of pin headers (so that the PCB can be used as a plugin module).

Would there be any negative consequences when one of the options is disconnected. Would the unconnected trace be especially susceptible to producing or receiving noise over a case where it would be connected?

Would this generally be considered bad design practice to even have multiple options on the same PCB far apart?[image]

Comment: This question is way to generic for a topic which strongly depends on a lot of parameters. E.g. frequency of EMI and signals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A truly definitive answer might be too long, so I will try to highlight some of the concerns rather than be comprehensive.

First, for high speed digital or sensitive analog signals, it is best to avoid this practice. High speed traces suffer signal degradation if there are long stubs. For inputs (for example a microphone input), long traces can become pickup antennas for low level noise. This will normally not be a problem for slow (<1 MHz) digital or full swing (rail-to-rail) analog. Examples of signals I would NOT fork are ethernet, USB, or microphones. It would be catastrophic for an RF antenna also. You cannot put random forks into RF feeds.

Barring that, there are mostly system level design issues. The kind of things to consider are how easy would it be for someone to accidentally use both interfaces, and if they did, would that be a problem? For example, if one of the connections is a power input, is there a possibility that someone would connect two different power supplies at the same time? Would that be bad? You would, in effect, be shorting together two external power supplies using the traces on your PCB.

If it was an audio input, and someone might hook up different audio signals to the two different inputs, would that harm one of the audio sources?

The situation for signal outputs is less problematic, as long as they are not too high speed, as previously mentioned, there is not likely to be any problem if you send a signal to two different receivers at the same time.

For signaling systems that are inherently robust, even when two outputs are connected together, such as RS232 or any type of open-collector based system, there is little potential for harm. RS232 is supposed to be designed so two outputs can be connected together indefinitely without permanent damage. So there is not too much danger there. A lot of so-called RS232 interfaces are now really TTL level devices and may not be as robust.

A lot of serial communication schemes use open-collector outputs. I2C for example. No danger with that. It just won't work properly if things are not connected in sane fashion.

There is one more thing to watch out for. It is not exactly related to your question, but it is similar. If you have a digital input and there is no output driving it and there is a long trace, that input needs a reasonably strong pullup or pulldown to avoid accidental switching. Or, you can use a capacitor in conjunction with a weak pullup or pulldown. Otherwise a nearby voltage spike might couple in by way of the trace and cause unintended switching.

Comment: Yes I could write a book too on crosstalk of unused traces from experience.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 one design I worked on had a problem where it was so ESD senstive that some Canadian testers said they could set it on a rug, walk around it in a circle and it would reset. (It was winter and very dry air). If I remember right it was an interrupt pin with a long trace. No code to disable or handle the interrupt. No capacitor. Just a weak pullup. When I shipped them a unit with a 22pF capacitor on the input, everything was fine. We found it all in time for production. But it was a learning experience. Many years ago.

Comment: Tek 200MHz Fet probes would blow the 0.5pF front end just looking sideways and raising a leg before heel straps were mandatory on both feet. We bought a tester and generated 200V doing this, V=Q/C

Answer (score 2):

Each trace is just one electrode to a stray capacitance.  The impedance of the node , Z(f) and the trace gap to another signal determines the crosstalk.  There are tools and fundamental theory to help compute this but complicated by layout differences. If it’s a critical analog low level signal, you might use a ground plane or coplanar GND thin guard tracks to shunt stray noise.

Answer (score 1):

One thought would be 0 ohm shunts for the alternate paths, so a simple stuffing change can choose the path?  Or, in a industrial world at lower frequencies one could even use plug jumpers or a dip switch.

In the world of large transients (lightning, large esd, industrial switching transients) having the duplicate traces both connected could cause damage (in those cases look to protection with zener diodes/TV's/mov to gnd vs diode to the power rail).